# Can't execute prepared statements using nested while loops

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble with changing over some code from old style mysql queries to being prepared. I assume the problem is due to the fact that I'm using multiple whiles which each have their own query in which is causing problems cause only one prepared statement can be active at a time.

EDIT: If anyone cares, I've made it work with only 2 loops like so -

```
function createDeskMenu()
{
    global $bookingTimes, $dbconn;
    $day0 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y"));

    $query = "SELECT location FROM location";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$query);
    mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $location = $row['location'];
        echo "<h3>$location</h3><div>";
        $query = $dbconn -> prepare("SELECT COALESCE( CountDesk, 0 ) total, name, d.desk_id, phone, fax, dock, pc FROM desk d LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(booked.desk_id) CountDesk, desk_id FROM booked WHERE booking_id >=?)b ON d.desk_id = b.desk_id WHERE location=?");
        $query->bind_param("is",$day0, $location);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($totalCount,$name,$desk_id,$phone,$fax,$dock,$pc);
        while($query->fetch()) {
            $total = count($bookingTimes) * 14 - $totalCount;
            echo '<a href="?page=desk&desk='.$desk_id.'"><div class="desk"><b>'.$name.' 
            ('.$total.' Available Bookings)</b><li>Facilities:';
            if($phone){echo " Phone,";}if($fax){echo " Fax Machine,";}if($dock){echo " Laptop Dock.";}if($pc){echo " Desktop Workstation.";}
            echo '</li></div></a><hr />';
        }
        $query->close();
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted any debugging at all using `echo` or `var_dump()` to see where the code is breaking? Btw you can do this all in one query, no need to run 3 separate ones.

Comment: Yeah I can see the problem, it's because I'm closing the queries before the loop has finished so the data isn't there for it to get when it loops around again. If I don't tell the queries to close though then the 2 in the middle fail because the first query is still open :P

Comment: How can it be done in a single query? I'm racking my brain on this... I know it looks ugly but I can't see a way of tidying it up... could you help?

Comment: See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Yeah it's not the statement I'm too concerned about, it's the php to make it build a table out of the data that I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: If you used a single statement you would need only one `while()` loop.

Comment: no because it has a minimum of two loops in it. The location which under that has however many desks.

Comment: So you must first try with two loops at most. Then debugging must be simpler for you.

Comment: Where does `$day0` come from? I'm trying to do it for you, but got stuck there since that is apparently passed to query, but is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: sorry, it calls today's date in PHP.

Comment: Timestamp of today. An example of it's output would be this - 1358121600.

Comment: Why are you preparing the statement over and over? You could re-use the same statement and just bind different values to it on each iteration.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, feeela. My knowledge of how prepared statements work is very limited. If you could show me what you mean that would be good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `prepare()` a statement while the connection has rows waiting to be fetched from another statement. You must first either close the previous result set or fetch all rows from it.

#### However...

I don't see the need for the outer query which retrieves `location` *at all*, as it has no `WHERE` clause. You are selecting *all* locations, and can therefore omit that part entirely. All you are using the outer loop for is to create a `<h3>` for each location, and this is extremely wasteful ( in addition to originally causing you breakage in the code)

Instead, do one query and in the fetch loop, check if the location has changed. When it changes, output your header

```
echo "<h3>$location</h3><div>";
```

So remove the outer query and loop entirely, and use a pattern like the following to detect changes in `location`.  Make sure to `ORDER BY location` so they are sorted for you.

**No** bound parameters are needed. You can do this with a query() call since the location is no longer variable and `$day0` is known to be a timestamp from `mktime()`.

```
// Substitute a query() call and $day0 can be inserted directly.
// This one query fetches all locations sorted...
$query = $dbconn->query("
  SELECT
   COALESCE( CountDesk, 0 ) total,
   name,
   d.desk_id,
   phone,
   fax,
   dock,
   pc
 FROM 
   desk d
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT COUNT(booked.desk_id) CountDesk, desk_id FROM booked WHERE booking_id >= $day0
   )b ON d.desk_id = b.desk_id 
 ORDER BY location");

// Store the last location in a variable which starts empty...
$location = "";

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
  // on change of $location, update the variable.
  if ($location !== $row['location']) {
    $location = $row['location'];
    // And output the new location value
     echo "<h3>$location</h3><div>";
  }

  // Do the rest of your loop.
  $total = count($bookingTimes) * 14 - $row['total'];
  echo '<a href="?page=desk&desk='.$row['desk_id'].'"><div class="desk"><b>'.$row['name'].' 
  ('.$total.' Available Bookings)</b><li>Facilities:';
  if($row['phone']){
    echo " Phone,";
  }
  if($row['fax']){ 
    echo " Fax Machine,";
  }
  if($row['dock']){
    echo " Laptop Dock.";
  }
  if($row['pc']){
    echo " Desktop Workstation.";
  }
  echo '</li></div></a><hr />';
}
$row->close();
echo '</div>';
```

Now on to the reason it was failing....  You cannot `prepare()` a new statement while there are rows remaining to be fetched from a previous statement or query. You must first either fetch all the rows, or close the statement with `$stmt->close()`. So effectively you cannot nest fetch loops.

The better method is to first fetch all rows into an array and then loop over that array:

```
while ($row = $first_query->fetch()) {
  // Append all onto an array
  $first_query_rows[] = $row;
}
// Then loop over that
foreach ($first_query_rows as $row) {
  // Do a new query with $row
}
```

Usually though, this can be solved with a proper `JOIN`.

Comment: I like what you've done there... Thanks for all the explaination work you've done, too :) I can't get your code working yet but I'll have a stab at it, getting a "Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array" error from the line "if ($location !== $query['location']) {" but I'll work on it

Comment: @Steve You're welcome - I didn't notice until after I finished that you updated the code to your current working solution.  This is much more efficient though.

Comment: @Steve Give it a try if you are able to work more on this chunk of code.

Comment: Yeah looks good, still can't get it to work for the above comment reasons... it doesn't seem to like the results being in an array format? Any ideas?

Comment: aha! the statement isn't outputting the location name. edit: Still not the problem, though...

Comment: @Steve Oops, all those `$query[]` should be `$row[]` since it was fetched as `$row = $query->fetch-assoc()`

Comment: Yeah just spotted that and was about to say :D